# .NET extension method conflict resolution of like named methods?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Our shop has a core library that provides an extension method `First` that actually does what Linq's `FirstOrDefault` does.  Our methods were in use before we ever made use of Linq.  Linq references were added later and doing so did not cause any issues.  The applications that used the core were able to continue calling `First` and getting our method vs. the Linq one of the same name.  Recently this changed when our Core was built with changes than span a month's time.  Now it resolves `First` to Linq's version instead of custom version.

The point of extension methods is that you don't qualify them.  You call

```
PeopleTable.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow)().First
```

instead of

```
utlCore.First(PeopleTable.Rows.OfType(Of DataRow)())
```

so its impractical to revisit the code an attempt to qualify the namespace.  I know it makes sense to retro the core to do away with the conflict and to simply use `FirstOrDefault`, but that's a larger and later todo.

Clearly there is some prioritization with how these extension methods are resolved.  I'm not aware of what would have changed to cause this prioritization to fall out of whack.  Where would you start looking?  What could cause this?

Comment: "Our methods were in use before Linq" - how is that possible as an extension method? Extension methods were introduced at the same time as LINQ...

Comment: You'll need to provide the signature of your `First` method and the compile-time type in the actual use case in order for us to really give concrete details about the overload resolution steps.

Comment: Did you add a reference to LINQ in the core during your changes? Also, are both LINQ and your Core referenced in the same scope of consuming code, if so, why are you trying to interchange them in the same consumer scope, your asking for trouble.

Comment: @JonSkeet remember, you can "enable" extension methods on 2.0 by redeclaring the `ExtensionAttribute` in the right namespace. :)

Comment: @Mario: Right, that makes more sense. I suggest you edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: @JerKimball: That's not the same as being in use "before LINQ" though.

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair point - but I think that's what he *meant*. (reading above comments) Or not... *shrug*

Comment: No need to get sidetracked by improper phrasing.  We've been using Linq for a long time now and this conflict has come about until just recently.

Comment: Should be simple enough to: 1) remove all `using System.Linq` references from relevant files` 2) refactor your `First` method to have another name, or even just to `FirstOrDefault` using VS or other editor tools 3) Add the linq references back in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you "enabled" extension methods via the "`ExtensionAttribute` hack", which is how you have extension methods and not LINQ...

As for why you're seeing this problem now, you've likely included this somewhere in the new code:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Since that brings `System.Linq.Enumerable` into scope, now you have ambiguity between your `First` and Linq's `First` - You can *sorta* control this with namespace aliasing...here's a throwaway example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
// don't add this, lest you bring it in
//using System.Linq;
using Linq = System.Linq.Enumerable;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var values = new List<int>(Linq.Range(0, 10));
            var useLinqFirst = Linq.First(values);
            Console.WriteLine("LINQ First(): {0}", useLinqFirst);
            var useMyFirst = values.First();
            Console.WriteLine("My First(): {0}", useMyFirst);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static class Ext
    {
        public static T First<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Using my First!");
            var e = src.GetEnumerator();
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                return e.Current;
            }
            return default(T);
        }
    }
}
```

Honestly, I'd just retrofit to use LINQ's `First` \ `FirstOrDefault` - far safer in the long run, since somewhere, somebody is going to forget they can't include the Linq namespaces, and you'll be back in the same situation.

Comment: Note that if you do this you can't use any of the LINQ mentods (even those other than `First`) as extension methods.  That could be a...problem.

Comment: @Servy Absolutely - hence the suggestion to just bite the bullet and do the retrofit. This method is in every sense of the word undesirable.

Comment: I dunno what happened.  For now I just added another `First` method with greater specificity.  It takes a generic array instead of a generic enumerable.

Comment: I think in the long term we are simply going to remove the conflict.